# Updating uitableview cell changes subsequent cells in same index

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, parse-platform

I am relatively new to objective c, so this might be a dumb question. I am using parse to search for users that a person can add. Essentially, when the user searches for usernames, the table view is populated with the names of users that the user can add as friends. Each cell should have a uibutton whose image is a plus sign, but if the user has the person in their friends list, it should show a green check mark.

My issue is that once a tableviewcell's button is a green check mark, all subsequent cells in that same position in the tableview also have green check marks. Any help is appreciated!

(searchresults is an array of PFUsers)

This is some of my cell for row method:

```
UIButton *addButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

[addButton setTag:indexPath.row];
[addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus sign blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addButton setEnabled:YES];

if ([[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"friends"] containsObject:[[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"username"]]) {
    [addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green check mark.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addButton setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean "all subsequent cells in that same position"?  Are you using a split view or something?

Comment: I am just using one uitableview, but if I search for the letter "a", and two users show up and the first row's cell has the modified green check mark image, if I search "m", and three users show up, the first row of that result will have the modified green check mark image as well, even if that user is not in my friends list. Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Breakpoint through your app - does it go into your if block for the green check marks when there shouldn't be? If it doesn't, it's probably because of the dequeueCell.

Comment: I agree with LyricalPanda. If so, maybe create a new type of custom cell to handle the first index.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I'll debug and see what I can figure out!